Single-word request: synonym verb for possessive "have"/"possess"
As far as I can tell, there are two meanings of "have" with regard to possession (there's also a third structural meaning but that is not relevant to the question):
The first is truly possessing, as in owning, an object.


I have/possess/own a car.


The second is "possessing" an attribute or characteristic (whether physical or abstract).


She has blue eyes.
She has a name.
The car has a (red exterior/red paint job/shiny finish).
The car has a registration number.


Dictionaries use "to be marked or characterized by" and "to be identified or distinguished by".
Is there an active verb I can use as a synonym for "have"/"possess" in a all the four sentences above that distinguishes between the two types of "possessing"?  Thesauruses have not come up with an answer.  Thanks in advance.

I can't think of one. 'Sports' and 'disports', I'd avoid.

What is your goal in finding a different word than has?

You can reword: "Her eyes are blue."

But I'm with @TinfoilHat: Are you worried that someone will think that she owns blue eyes? It doesn't happen.

That car rocks a shiny finish!

You want two different verbs, or one verb?

The distinction between owning something and having something as a characteristic is often fuzzy. Does a car own its paint? Does it own its wheels? Does a person own their name? Does a business own their trademark? Does a person own their eyes?

The 'active verb' would be the verb 'to be' She is blue-eyed. Her name is xxxx. The car exterior is red. The registration number of the car is xxxxx. One is what an attribute attributes. You are correct, conceptually that an attribute is not a possession. But idiomatically we accept it to be so and, theoretically it is ambiguous.. She has (spare) blue eyes (in her handbag).
